# Indices and Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all the possible value of x 
in this equation
\begin{eqnarray*}
2\times 5^{x+1}=1+\frac{3}{5^x}
\end{eqnarray*}
Thanks in abundance

I don't know how to use iteratiom to kill it.
Pls help me out

Comment: Let $u=5^x$ and then solve the quadratic.

Comment: Do you mean 
\begin{eqnarray*}
2 \times 5^{x+1}=1+\frac{3}{5^x}
\end{eqnarray*}
now ?

Comment: yes that was how it was asked

Answer (score 2):

We have to solve the equation
$$
2\cdot (5^x+1)=1+\frac{3}{5^x}
$$
Let's multiply its both sides  by $5^x$ to get rid of the unpleasant fraction:
$$
2\cdot 5^x\cdot(5^x+1)=5^x+3
$$
\begin{align}
&\Leftrightarrow 2\cdot(5^x)^2+2\cdot 5^x=5^x+3\\
&\Leftrightarrow 2\cdot(5^x)^2+5^x-3=0
\end{align}
Put $y=5^x$. The latter equation can be expressed now in the form
$$
2y^2+y-3=0
$$
And we solve it in $y$:
$$
\Delta=25
$$
$$
y_1=\frac{-1-\sqrt{\Delta}}{4}=-\frac{3}{2}
$$
$$
y_2=\frac{-1+\sqrt{\Delta}}{4}=1
$$
Now it is the time to look back how we have defined $y$, namely $y=5^x$. This means that $y$ cannot be negative and in result, only the second root is possible. Hence
$$
y=1
$$
which gives
$$
5^x=1
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow x=0
$$